# How to import a custom package into Scala Play! Framework 2.0

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm working in Play! Framework 2.0 with Scala on sublime text editor. I wanted to create some custom helpers which are just a few methods relating to the controller or goal. So I created a folder in the "app" directory called "helpers," for example I have a helper called SiteHelper.scala

in /app/helpers/SiteHelper.scala I start with

```
package helpers

class SiteHelper {

   def method() = {}

}
```

Now in my controller I want to be able to do this: `import helpers.SiteHelper`

then use the method in my controller: `SiteHelper.method()`

When I try this I get a compilation error: "not found: value SiteHelper"

How can I use my helper classes in my controllers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want to use an object instead of a class

```
package helpers

object SiteHelper {

 def method() = {}
}
```

Then in you constroller:

```
import helpers.SiteHelper

object MyConstroller {
  SiteHelper.method()
}
```